# Order by Absolute value in NHibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I have a Criteria query and I need to achieve this SQL order by query:

```
ORDER BY Name, DecimalColumn, ABS(DecimalNegativeColumn)
```

My Order By Criteria looks like this

```
var result = criteria
                .Add(conjunction)
                .AddOrder(new Order("Name", true))
                .AddOrder(new Order("DecimalColumn", true))
                .AddOrder(new Order("DecimalNegativeColumn", true))
                .List<MyClass>();
```

What can I do?

Comment: I bet you can't do this without using sql/hql or sorting the list after its returned. Hibernate can be lame sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be very easy. We can use the extensibility, which comes with NHibernate. When building the `Criteria`, we call `.AddOrder()` and pass the instance of the object `Order`. So we can pass even *Custom* one:

```
public class CustomOrder : Order
{
    public CustomOrder(string propertyName, bool ascending) 
        : base(propertyName, ascending) { }

    public override SqlString ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
    {
        var sqlString = new SqlString(propertyName);
        return sqlString.Append(this.ascending ? " asc" : " desc");
    }
}
```

So the call would be:

```
.AddOrder(new CustomOrder("Abs(DecimalNegativeColumn)", true))
```

Or whatever needed and valid *order by* string instead of the `"Abs(DecimalNegativeColumn)"`

Comment: Simple and elegant... An that's why I love NHibernate

Comment: It's actually easier than that. You could just use a SqlProjection. No class needed.

Comment: @AgustinMeriles Great if that helped ;) BTW I do like your point, that's why I do love NHibernate ;) ;)

Answer (score 3):

Radim's solution works, but this one doesn't require additional classes:

```
.AddOrder(Order.Asc(Projections.SqlFunction(
    "abs", NHibernateUtil.Int32, Projections.Property("DecimalNegativeColumn"))))
```

I'm just telling NH to project the DecimalNegativeColumn through the `abs` function, which is defined by the `Dialect`.

Comment: Nice, really nice solution

Answer (score 1):

You can create a computed property in the `Order` class. Just add another property using `Formula`. So if you are using Fluent NHibernate:

```
Map(t => t.AbsDecimalNegativeColumn).Formula("ABS(DecimalNegativeColumn)");
```

Then you can add this to your `Criteria` just like any other property:

```
AddOrder(new Order("AbsDecimalNegativeColumn", true));
```